# Failure Delivering Result Result Info

Tags: java, android

I have researched this a lot on Stack Overflow, but the problem persists. I have a `main` activity and it calls `startActivityForResult` for my `takeapicture` activity. Here is my code in `takeapicture` that returns the results:

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        pictureFile = null;
        try {
            pictureFile = createImageFile(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e.getCause());
            System.out.println("lol");}
        if (pictureFile == null){
            System.out.println("lol");
            return;
        }

        try {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }
        System.out.println(pictureFile.getAbsoluteFile());
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("SavedImageDirectory", pictureFile);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
};
```

When running this, I get the following error on the first line that uses the `SavedImageDirectory` extra:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{...
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
....
```

It looks like the extra has a `null` vaue, but I don't see where it could go wrong. Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how do you read that extra, getStringExtra() ? this might be the problem as you are setting a File object in that extra, so getting the value as String Extra will be NULL.

i am not sure but i think the `putExtra("",File)` will be the `Serializable value` version of `putExtra()` so you need to read it as `getSerializableExtra()` or simply add the file name in the extra

```
i.putExtra("SavedImageDirectory", pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

or to be more specific you may add file name too

```
i.putExtra("SavedImageDirectory", pictureFile.getAbsolutePath() + pictureFile.getName());
```

this way, you can read it as a String Extra.

Answer (score 0):

All the documention on Intent.putExtra(name, value)  says  'name' should include a package prefix, not just a string like "SavedImageDirectory"

Comment: Still does not work. I changed it to the package prefix but the problem persists, with the same error message.